# Highlighting comments in Python script

Tags: python, ide, comments, pycharm

I am using Pycharm. I often use `# TODO`, which highlights the comment in blue. Is it possible to highlight other comments in a different colour, using other keywords?

For example, I would like to be able to highlight important notes in red, say using `# NOTE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a custom highlight for comments in Python scripts, go to `File -> Settings -> Editor -> TODO` and add a new pattern:

[image]

Configure, as needed:

[image]

Bright Red is hard to miss:

[image]

[PyCharm HELP](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2017.1/todo.html)